# My parcel React website on localhost takes 10 seconds time when opened with chrome inspect tab and loads quickly when inspect tab is not opened

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, parceljs

I am learning react from namaste react course of akshay saini.
I created 2 files.
Index.html
script.js

Then i initiated npm init.
After that i added parcel to it and then ran the
npx parcel index.html command.
The website started running on localhost://1234
When i opened it on chrome , everything worked fine and quickly.
But when i opened the chrome devtools using inspect button , then opened the network tab and then refreshed the website , it took 10 long seconds on network tab just to load the same website now.
The file index.8cfc62b9.js is taking 10 long seconds.This is the js minified file in dist folder of my project.

I have not created react app using create react app. I did it by adding parcel seperately to my react project.
Why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Your inspector]

This option in your inspector is used to set the internet loading speed. You can change it to "No throttling" so that your page loads with normal speed.

Comment: Hey Thanks. It worked. I have been stuck on it for like 2 hours.

Comment: Hey , but what about the size , its 1.7 mb which i think is so much for just printing hello. Why is it?

Comment: The script includes every logic from React, including the hooks and APIs that you do not use, and those available only during development, such as live reloading. Basically that's the entire React library in the script.